# How to make a function that returns the factorial of each integer in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, if-statement

I'm new to coding and have been given this question that I cannot seem to get right:

Create a function that takes an array of positive integers and returns an array of the factorials of these numbers.

```
  E.g. [4, 3, 2] => [24, 6, 2]
```

The factorial of a number is the product of that number and all the integers below it.

```
  E.g. the factorial of 4 is 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24
```

If the number is less than 0, reject it.

The code that I have created is this;

```
function getFactorials(nums) {
   if (nums === 0 || nums === 1)
      return 1;
   for (var i = nums - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      nums *= i;
   }
   return nums;
}
```

The code is being run against this test;

```
describe("getFactorials", () => {
  it("returns [] when passed []", () => {
    expect(getFactorials([])).to.eql([]);
  });
  it("returns one factorial", () => {
    expect(getFactorials([3])).to.eql([6]);
  });
  it("returns multiple factorials", () => {
    expect(getFactorials([3, 4, 5])).to.eql([6, 24, 120]);
  });
  it("returns largest factorials", () => {
    expect(getFactorials([3, 8, 9, 10])).to.eql([6, 40320, 362880, 3628800]);
  });
});
```

How should I do this?

Comment: You should create a factorial function that only deals with one number, then, just `map` it over the list. Tying the handling of multiple numbers and the computation of each factorial will just confuse matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, make a recursive function that calculates the factorial of a single number:

```
function factorial(num) {
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return num * factorial(num - 1);
}
```

Then to do it for an array, just use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like so:

```
function getFactorials(arr) {
    var result = arr.map(x => factorial(x));
    return result;
}
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
 

function factorial(num) {
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return num * factorial(num - 1);
}

function getFactorials(arr) {
    var result = arr.map(x => factorial(x));
    return result;
}

console.log(getFactorials([4, 8, 10])); 
console.log(getFactorials([]));
console.log(getFactorials([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You’re missing a closing parenthesis in your `getFactorials` function.

Comment: No problem @JackBashford

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate function into two functions, one for iterating the array and collecting the calculated values and the other to get the facorial of a number.

```js
function getFactorials(nums) {
    var result = [],
        i;
        
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        result.push(getFactorial(nums[i]));
    }
    return result;
} 

function getFactorial(n) {
   if (n === 0 || n === 1) return 1;
   return n * getFactorial(n - 1);
}

console.log(getFactorials([]));
console.log(getFactorials([3]));
console.log(getFactorials([3, 4, 5]));
console.log(getFactorials([3, 8, 9, 10]));
```

Answer (score 1):

This method will take an array of numbers and will return an array of factorial numbers of them,

```
function getFactorials(array) {
        var facArray = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            num = array[j];
            if (num === 0 || num === 1)
                return 1;
            for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
                num *= i;
            }
            facArray.push(num);
        }
        return facArray;

    }

console.log(getFactorials([4, 3, 2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFactorials(nums) {
  return numbers = Array.from(nums).map(function factorializeSingleNumber(num) {
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) return 1
    else return num * factorializeSingleNumber(num - 1)
  })
}
```

The best way I find of tackling these is to break the problem down. So in this case, work a solution that factorializes a single number. When that is working you can add this 'working code' into a map or loop, to work through the array.

My above solution uses recursion but could be a simple 'for loop' too